Staging Ground comment UX causes users to forget to leave a review
I've seen several instances where reviewers have left a comment with feedback but forgot to leave a review. For example, in this question two users left a comment but forgot to submit a review. I believe this is because the comments are a separate actionable item from the review itself.
This makes sense for an interface like the review queues but since Staging Ground posts also show up in the question listing this doesn't work that well because the users opening the post are used to leaving comments with feedback and then just closing the post.
Can we update the UX to guide the reviewers in some way to leave a review when they comment?

Just to give a different perspective on this: in my first interaction with a Staging Ground page, I didn't "forget" to leave a review, I consciously interacted with the parts of the page I understood (comments) and left alone the parts I didn't.
I was on mobile, so the label is just "Actions", and I simply assumed it was a toolbox with some things which I could do, not something I was expected to do. Admittedly, it shows "Please select one..." as the placeholder, but unfortunately I've become accustomed to UIs which use that blindly for both optional and mandatory fields.
I also don't frequently interact with Review Queues, which I think this part of the flow is modelled on. Unlike traditional review queues, Staging Ground questions show up mixed into search results, so I wasn't consciously "reviewing" anything, I was just clicking on a search result and interacting with it. The UX needs to somehow highlight that my normal habits (comment and move on) are not quite what's expected for these results.

To be honest, I think this may be the worst problem of that UI.

I think the problem right now is that the feedback option and the review option are too far apart. For any longer question, they will not even be on the same screen.

It would be a good idea to add an option to also leave a review as you leave a comment. At the very least, this would be a reminder to users that they should review. It would also make the action immediate.
I imagine something akin to:


This is an illustration, not meant to be the final result.

Yeah I noticed this too. For me, I even almost did this a couple of times myself. I'd leave a comment, then (since I don't like using the regular "take me to whatever the system thinks I should try to review next" flow, and prefer to skim the listing page) I'd go to close the tab and almost forget to submit a review action. For my use case, it'd help if Confirmation before closing of tab/browser was used when I've left a new comment but haven't submitted a review action yet.
